# Django return .html file directly without parsing for template tags at all

Tags: python, django, javascriptmvc

I'm writing a single view Javascript application with a Django backend that only needs to return the initial index.html and all other templates come from a CDN. My problem is that this first index.html file is parsing out some of my "{{}}" handlebars which I wanted to leave for the JS library to interpret.

I **DO NOT** want to use 'verbatim' or 'raw' or any additional tags because I don't want any django specific stuff in my static template files.

A possible alternative answer to this would be desmonstrating how to to make your inital index HTML response also come from the CDN but I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: How about serving the file plain [statically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and configuring your web server to serve it in the URL namespace you want (e.g. RewriteRule/Alias in Apache)?

Comment: flat pages? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/

Comment: @gertvdijk hmm that's a decent idea. I use NGINX in prod for static files so perhaps I should change my development setup to better reflect that and include the initial index.html request.

Comment: @EsseTi thanks, I'm going to read up on this now

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to render a template, simply don't render it. Django won't render anything unless you specifically call `template.render` or one of the shortcuts.

If you just want to return an HTML file, you could just open it as a normal file, read it, then return the content as the response.

Alternatively, as suggested in the comment, you can serve it as a static file.